# How to load a image from url to UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, storyboard

I am new to iOS developer, using `Storyboard` I get `Image` from the URL and load an image to the **UITableviewcell** when scroll the `tableview` the table will scroll very slowly and struck to scroll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here check ou the following links , you should use lazy loading for this,

[Lazy load images in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130089/lazy-load-images-in-uitableview)

[Loading images from a URL into a UITableViewCell's UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390151/loading-images-from-a-url-into-a-uitableviewcells-uiimageview)

[Load image to a tableView from URL iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565123/load-image-to-a-tableview-from-url-iphone-sdk)

[Lazy load images in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531482/lazy-load-images-in-uitableviewcell)

Comment: using json parser i get image from url and i load to tableview problem is when i am scroll the table view it will struck to scroll

Answer (score 0):

You should use lazy loading of image in your cells. The slowness or stuck is happening because you are fetching the image (..ie a network activity) in your main thread or the UI thread.

You can get a lot of tutorial in net for loading images async. 
Here is a tutorial from Apple : [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

see the answer from this question for AsynchImage..
[iphone-download-asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152882/iphone-download-asynchronous-work-but-load-asynchronous-dont)

also use AsynchImage for download image and set in UITableViewCell as a image

[asynchronous-loading-of-images-in-a-uitableview](http://kosmaczewski.net/asynchronous-loading-of-images-in-a-uitableview/)