# array of images from json in to the CollectionView Custom cell swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to pass the data from my JSON Url to my collection view cell, so after parsing my json I have got array of URL links, the question is how to send it to cell imageView?

here is my code

```
import UIKit

class ItemsListViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

  var myItems = [Item]()


  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myItems.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.itemPriseLabel.text = myItems[indexPath.row].currentPrice

    let imageUrl =   myItems[indexPath.row].productImageUrl
    print(imageUrl)


    cell.itemImage.image? = imageUrl[indexPath.row]

    return cell
  }

  var category1: Categories?

  @IBOutlet weak var colectionViewVariable: UICollectionView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    downloadJSON3 {
        self.colectionViewVariable.reloadData()

    }

    colectionViewVariable?.dataSource = self
    colectionViewVariable?.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a image from url to UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303008/how-to-load-a-image-from-url-to-uitableviewcell)

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Comment: Please show the code and describe what "does not work"

Comment: I have solved the problem,please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func getDataFromUrl(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        completion(data, response, error)
    }.resume()
}

func downloadImage(url: URL) {
    print("Download Started")
    getDataFromUrl(url: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)
        print("Download Finished")
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

> Duplicate: Answer found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift) I've stacked it into one concise answer but you should definitely read the answer as it is in the link as it is more complete and better altogether.

Answer (score 0):

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

```
    cell.itemPriseLabel.text = myItems[indexPath.row].currentPrice

    if let imageUrl = myItems[indexPath.row].productImageUrl.first {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageUrl, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, response != nil, error == nil else {return}


            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                let image = UIImage(data: data)

                if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {
                    cell.itemImage.image = image
                }

            })
        }).resume()

    }

    return cell
}
```